# JAX-RS: Is it possible to have an externally configurable @PATH?

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, wildfly

Is it possible to load the value for the @PATH annotation from configuration (web.xml, etc) for a given class?

```
@Path(<value loaded from config>)
public class myRestService {
...
```

Comment: Why don't we maybe start with a use case.  What is the use case for having the path configurable?

Answer (score 2):

Independent of JAX-RS: Annotations in Java are compile time constants so they can't be changed at runtime.

I don't know your use case but possible ways to change the values of the annotations are:

- Replacing variables before compilation, e.g. through a maven plugin.
- Adding the `@Path` annotations dynamically like [described here](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.de/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html).
- Using one generic ResourceClass mapped to `/*` which decides which [subresource](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/jaxrs-resources.html#d0e2184) should be returned.

No comment if one of these approaches makes sense as I don't know why you want to change them. As the URI names a resource I don't see any reason to change it. See also: [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html.en)

**Update:** [JAX_RS_SPEC-60](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-60) requests "A Dynamic way to register JAX-RS resources (not based on annotations)".

Answer (score 0):

According to JAX-RS specification ([here](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0_rev_A-mrel-eval-spec/index.html)), there is no standard way to do this, I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can add path programmatically, as shown in [JAX-RS Jersey, how to dynamic adding resources or providers to Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881986/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-dynamic-adding-resources-or-providers-to-application)

which means you can then wire it your configuration .