# How to dynamically add/remove resource endpoints at runtime in Jersey?

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs, dropwizard

I'm using dropwizards 1.3.5 and I want to create a gateway Api.

I want the api-gateway to front all api's behind it. Every api would subscribe to the gateway-api, then the gateway-api would create the according endpoints for contacting the specified api.

Is is possible to add resources at runtime?

I would want to do something like that :

Main

```
@Override
public void run(final Configuration configuration, final Environment environment) {

    environment.jersey().register(new SubscriberResource(environment));

}
```

SubscriberResource

```
@Path("/subscriber")
public class SubscriberResource {
public SubscriberResource(Environment environment) {
    this.environment = environment;
}
@POST
@Timed
public Response add() {
    environment.jersey().register(new newResource());
    return Response.status(Status.OK).build();
    }
}
```

I know the environment cannot be modified after initialization. Is there a way to reload the app or do this in any other way?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-RS Jersey, how to dynamic adding resources or providers to Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881986/jax-rs-jersey-how-to-dynamic-adding-resources-or-providers-to-application)